# JPA Criteria multiple predicate on join

Tags: jpa, join, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria, having

I'm using JPA criteria api because my query has dynamic where values. My Criteria needs to join 2 table like this:

```
SELECT p.name, upl.score 
FROM place p 
left join place.userPlaceLike upl on p.place_id=upl.place_id AND upl.user_id=1  
GROUP BY p.place_id 
HAVING count(place_id)>1
```

After quite some searching it seems that we cannot currently archive this with JPA Criteria . Is this right ?

The other solution is to use Hibernate Critera like this:

```
.createAlias("p.uerPlaceLike", "upl", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("upl.userPlaceLike.idUser", 1))
```

This indeed works, but now my other problem is that apparently Hibernate Criteria doesn't support HAVING COUNT ??

What are my choice now ? Am I force to use HQL?

Comment: Where have you read that JPA Criteria API doesn't support the operand `GROUP BY [] HAVING []`? That's implemented, check out the Javadoc of [`CriteriaQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) and, if still unclear, come back with a more detailed question including your failed attempts and adding the relevant part of the Entity definitions.

Comment: org.hibernate.Critera doesn't support Having Count. java.persistence.Criteria does.  But.. org.hibernate.Critera support multiple condition on join whereas java.persistence.Criteria doesnt.... (at least thats what I understood)

Comment: Correct, JPA Criteria doesn't support joins on multiple conditions, but this can be easily worked around by using WHERE predicate conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately my query needs to use this extra join condition. because i "need" to retrieve info that might no be in my second table (so i need to have these null values) if I use where it will discard me these rows